# Windows 7 64-bit Internet Explorer 9 Crash(APPCRASH jscript9.dll)

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7-x64

I have a web application that uses ASP.Net MVC and Ext JS 3.1 and I get the below error consistently for a page where I try to get the JSON value from a store and IE 9 crashes. The page works fine on other browsers and IE 8/7.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: iexplore.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.8112.16421
  Application Timestamp:    4d76255d
  Fault Module Name:    jscript9.dll
  Fault Module Version: 9.0.8112.16434
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e28e66c
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0006c8a2
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: I have same problem with .NET application which show maps using google API ...

Comment: @Alsin - if you are still having this issue, try what I suggested in my answer, I came across the same problem doing the same as you today and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

On 64 bit machines this happens after a windows update, which I didn't bothered to find out which one. But after re-registering the DLL (as below) this problem can be resolved.

```
Open command prompt as an administrator and type below
C:\> regsvr32 jscript9.dll
```

This should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem go to the Debug tab in your project settings and make sure the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" setting is turned **on**

I encountered this same issue using Google Maps in a WebBrowser control.

I know I'm resurrecting an old question here, but hopefully it will help anyone coming across this page in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provided hot-fix for IE 9 on 13th Nov 2012. 
so, this issue will not be there with IE version of - 9.0.8112.16455 OR above.